# MS Access OpenRecordset - no current record

Tags: ms-access

After doing this:

```
Set rts = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

It always sees my RecordCount = 0.  However, it is wrong and even updates the results on my form, but my recordset has no records.

Please help!

Comment: `dbSeeChanges` makes me suspect that this Recordset involves one or more ODBC linked tables. Is that the case?

Comment: I'm slightly confused, you say your RecordCount is 0 and that you have no Records, sounds correct to me. However if it is just that your RecordCount should be greater than 0, then DAO recordsets usually require you to use `.MoveLast` to get the true RecordCount, you can then use `.MoveFirst` to get back to the start of your Recordset.

Comment: I was missing a reference to the fieldname in one of my queries and I did not notice it. It works now, thx for the help !